# Comparing a range of cells to a single cell and then increment a value

Tags: if-statement, filter, google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

I have a row that contains cells of either `YES` or `NO` and want to iterate through each cell in the row and see if its value is equal to another cell whose value is `YES` or `NO`. IF they are both `YES` or both `NO` I want to increment another cell by `1`.

I tried something like this but received an error:

```
=if (H2:N2 = P2, Q2+1, 0)
```

Can someone inform me why the above IF is not working and go into how possibly to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a filter. Like this:

=counta(filter(H2:N2,H2:N2=P2))